# Groovy inconsistent behavior when assigning a string to an integer

Tags: string, groovy, type-conversion, integer

When running this code:

```
String number = "1"
Integer x
println number
x = number
println(x)
```

the output is:

> 1
> 49

and when running this code:

```
String number = "10"
Integer x
println number
x = number
println(x)
```

I get:

> 10
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
> cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class
> 'java.lang.Integer'

I know the problem can be solved with `toInteger` and it would be best not to get into situations like this, but the way it behaves it's inconsistent and I am curious about the inner workings.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner workings of your first example is that the [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of the character `0` is 48 and for `1` is 49.

In other words, the expression:

```
Integer x = "1"
```

is asking groovy to convert the character `1` to an integer which it happily does and gives you back the integer ascii value which is 49. The same happens in java:

```
char c = "1".charAt(0);
int i = (int) c;
System.out.println(i);
```

Which prints 49 as well.

This in contrast to the string "10", it is no longer possible to coerce those two characters to a single int (ascii value) as there are now two characters.